# python program stuck in window

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I've got a script in python2.7 write in Pycharm IDE on windows, can I run same program in ubuntu ?

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class App:
    label_rgb_template = "R: {0}, G: {1}, B: {2}"

    def __init__(self):
        self.picked_image_filename = None
        self.image = None
        self.tk_image = None
        self.image_id = None
        self.image_filename = None
        self.current_size = None
        self.current_factor = None
        self.root = root = Tk()

        self.offset_x = 0
        self.offset_y = 0

        root.title('Biomteria')
        root.size = (500, 500)
        root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        root.bind("<Configure>", self.resize_handler)
        root.bind("<Key>", self.root_key_press_handler)

        frame = Frame(root)
        frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N + S + W + E)
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(10, weight=1)

        btn_open = Button(frame, text='otworz plik', command=self.open_image)
        btn_save = Button(frame, text='zapisz plik', command=self.save_image)
        btn_zoom_in = Button(frame, text='+', command=self.zoom_in)
        btn_zoom_out = Button(frame, text='-', command=self.zoom_out)

        self.entry_red = entry_red = Spinbox(frame, from_=0, to=255)
        label_entry_red = Label(frame, text="R:")

        self.entry_green = entry_green = Spinbox(frame, from_=0, to=255)
        label_entry_green = Label(frame, text="G:")

        self.entry_blue = entry_blue = Spinbox(frame, from_=0, to=255)
        label_entry_blue = Label(frame, text="B:")

        self.label_rgb_text = StringVar()
        self.label_rgb_text.set(self.label_rgb_template.format(0, 0, 0))

        label_rgb = Label(frame, textvariable=self.label_rgb_text)

        btn_open.grid(row=0, column=0)
        btn_save.grid(row=0, column=1)
        btn_zoom_in.grid(row=0, column=2)
        btn_zoom_out.grid(row=0, column=3)
        label_entry_red.grid(row=0, column=4)
        entry_red.grid(row=0, column=5)
        label_entry_green.grid(row=0, column=6)
        entry_green.grid(row=0, column=7)
        label_entry_blue.grid(row=0, column=8)
        entry_blue.grid(row=0, column=9)
        label_rgb.grid(row=0, column=10, sticky=E)

        self.canvas = canvas = Canvas(root)
        canvas.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N + S + W + E)
        canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.canvas_click_handler)
        canvas.bind("<Motion>", self.canvas_motion_handler)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def open_image(self):
        self.image_filename = image_filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(('All files', '*.*'),))
        self.image = Image.open(image_filename)
        self.image = self.image.convert("RGB")
        self.current_size = self.image.size
        self.current_factor = 1
        self.refresh()


    def save_image(self):
        image_filename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(initialfile=self.image_filename)
        self.image.save(image_filename)

    def zoom(self, factor):
        self.current_size = tuple((int(value * factor) for value in self.current_size))
        self.current_factor = int(self.current_factor * factor)
        self.refresh()

    def zoom_in(self):
        self.zoom(2)

    def zoom_out(self):
        self.zoom(0.5)

    def refresh(self):
        center = (self.canvas.winfo_width() / 2 + self.offset_x, self.canvas.winfo_height() / 2 + self.offset_y)
        self.canvas.delete(self.image_id)
        self.tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image.resize(self.current_size))
        self.image_id = self.canvas.create_image(center, image=self.tk_image)

    def resize_handler(self, evt):
        if self.image:
            self.refresh()

    def get_pixel_coords(self, evt):
        bbox = self.canvas.bbox(ALL)
        if bbox and bbox[0] <= evt.x <= bbox[2] and bbox[1] <= evt.y < bbox[3]:
            pixel_coords = evt.x - bbox[0], evt.y - bbox[1]
            return tuple((value / self.current_factor for value in pixel_coords))
        return None

    def canvas_click_handler(self, evt):
        pixel_coords = self.get_pixel_coords(evt)
        if pixel_coords:
            color = self.entry_red.get(), self.entry_green.get(), self.entry_blue.get()
            color = tuple(int(value) for value in color)
            self.image.putpixel(pixel_coords, color)
            self.refresh()

    def canvas_motion_handler(self, evt):
        pixel_coords = self.get_pixel_coords(evt)
        if pixel_coords:
            self.label_rgb_text.set(self.label_rgb_template.format(*self.image.getpixel(pixel_coords)))

    def root_key_press_handler(self, evt):
        code = evt.keycode
        print code
        if code == 37:
            self.offset_x -= 10
        if code == 38:
            self.offset_y -=10
        if code == 39:
            self.offset_x += 10
        if code == 40:
            self.offset_y += 10

        self.refresh()
```

I have to change something ?, becouse when I runing that script on ubuntu a script window opens, but buttons doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If this is all of your code, you're forgetting to create an instance of `App`. Add the following to the bottom of the file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```